# jQuery empty autocomplete list

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Thymeleaf form.

One of the input fields is like this:

```
            <input type ="text" id="customer" class="floatLabel" name="customer" th:field = "*{customer.idCustomer}">
            <label for="customer">Customer</label>
```

I want to use jQuery UI. In my Java app, it works and the app sends JSON with correct values. But my auto suggestion list is empty.

I included one css library in my html head section and few script libraries at the bottom of body part.

Libraries are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script>
     $("#customer").autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
       
       $.ajax({
        url: "/search_customer",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
         search: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {
         response( data );
        }
       });
      },
      select: function (event, ui) {
       // Set selection
       $('#customer').val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to input
       $('#customer').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
       return false;
      }
     });
```

Java controller:

```
@PostMapping("/search_customer")
@ResponseBody
public List<Object[]> searchTerm(@RequestParam(name = "search", required = false) String searchTerm)
{
    List<Object[]> customers = customerDAO.getCustomers(searchTerm);
    
    return customers;
}
```

JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ICustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerDTO, Integer>
{
    @Query(value = "SELECT c.idCustomer, c.ingameName FROM CustomerDTO c WHERE c.ingameName LIKE :term%")
    public List<Object[]> findCustomersAutocomplete(String term);
}
```

So, everything works fine, I get JSON array and each element has one integer and one string. In that thymeleaf input field I want labels to be string "ingameName" and value (user shouldn't see that) is idCustomer.

JSON that I received looks like this:

```
[[1, "customer1"], [3, "Customer2"]]
0: [1, "customer1"]
0: 1
1: "customer1"
1: [3, "Customer2"]
0: 3
1: "Customer2"
```

So I want labels to be customer1 and Customer2 and values that should be saved are 1 or 3.
But I don't know how to tell jQuery UI what is label and what is id?

I followed this tutorial:

https://makitweb.com/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-php-and-ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data recieve from backend(controller) is not in format which autocomplete plugin accept so you can create that format inside success function of ajax . You just need to loop through your `data` using *each* loop and then push array value in key-value pair in *JSON Array* and then pass same to your plugin.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var data = [
  [1, "Customer1"],
  [3, "Customer2"]
];
$("#customer").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    /*$.ajax({
        //some codes
      success: function( data )  {*/
    var json_array = [];
    //create format like autocompltee
    $(data).each(function(i, val) {
      //create obj and push value in main_array
      json_array.push({
        "label": val[1],
        "value": val[0]
      })
    })
    console.log(json_array)
    response(json_array);
    /* }
       });*/
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#customer').val(ui.item.label);
    $('#ids').val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="customer" class="floatLabel" name="customer">
<input type="text" id="ids">
<label for="customer">Customer</label>
```